# SortedSet Enumerate from a starting position

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I would like to enumerate a sortedset starting from a given position. Say my set contains [1,2,10,23,30]. I would like to search for 10 and then enumerate from that position. I believe enumeration from a fixed position in a sorted set runs in O(n) where n is the number of elements you want to visit. But accessing by index is O(log n). So if I tried to say find 10 and got index 2 and then did a for loop of index 2 - N that would be runtime O(n log n) which is not acceptable.

Anyone have any experience here?

Comment: If a set can be represented as a sequence, then why mySet.SkipWhile(x=>x<10) wouldn't work? I don't remember about SkipWhile, but Skip will check if your sequence is list, and if it is then it is optimized for O(1). SkipWhile cannot O(1) obviously, but it also can be optimized for quick search.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GetViewBetween](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381801.aspx). It is made for the purpose of range scans.

Whenever I use a new class I look at its members in Reflector to try to discover useful gems there.

Answer (score 0):

`s.SkipWhile(x => x < 10)` should be `O(n)`, where n is the number of elements in the list.

Moving from one element to the next is quick; moving to the *i* th element from the start if you look up by index might not be.